# Setting default value in emmet

Tags: html, emmet

I can generate 60 html links like :

```
a.onegame*60
```

How do I set the default innerHTML and attribute value for all of them instead of blank value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "default innerHTML" and "blank value"? Do you mean set unique text for all 60 links? or just placeholder values? Please clarify.

Comment: I meant any of them, with a default value or a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a placeholder, just use curly braces to add some default text for all of your links. For example, `a.onegame{test}*3` will give you

```
<a href="" class="onegame">test</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">test</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">test</a>
```

If you need to number the items, use Emmet's `$` feature, e.g. `a.onegame{test$}*3` outputs

```
<a href="" class="onegame">test1</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">test2</a>
<a href="" class="onegame">test3</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. Can I also update the `href` as the same way ?

Comment: Yeah, you can utilize $ in the same way. If this answer worked for you, could you vote up and mark this as the selected answer? It'll help filter the search queries on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can use this variable `$` to add any counter value and `{value}` to provide a value or placeholder in [emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/).

Such as `a.onegame{link $}` gives:

```
<a href="" class="onegame">link 1</a>
```

`$` starts with 1 here

To add the *href* value or any *attribute* the syntax is `[attr = value]` like:

`a.onegame[href=$]` gives:

```
<a href="1" class="onegame"></a>
```